# Overview of ISharedImages?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

The Java UI plugin provides the Interface [`ISharedImages`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/ui/ISharedImages.html) to access standard images which can be used in own plugins.

e.g.

```
Image image = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getSharedImages().getImage(ISharedImages.IMG_OBJ_ELEMENT);
```

This works very well but I did not find an overview of the available images. Can someone please point me to such a documentation?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Some of them you can find [here](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.pde.doc.user%2Fguide%2Ftools%2Fviews%2Fimage_browser_view.htm), but keep in mind that other 3rd party plugins can add another set of shared images for which, you would have to refer to that plugin documentation.

Comment: Thanks for that link, [this page](http://www.vorlesungsfrei.de/kai/index.php?location=eclipse&sub=sharedimages) shows all available images. How do other Plugins contribute images? Did you mean the `ImageRegistry`?

Answer (score 13):

You can use the **Plug-in Image Browser** which was added recently:

> Window > Show View > Other... > Plug-in Development > Plug-in Image
>   Browser

See also http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.pde.doc.user%2Fguide%2Ftools%2Fviews%2Fimage_browser_view.htm